# dataframe to dictionary of list of tuples grouped by key

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dataframe df that has that looks as follows:

```
        a    b    c    d
0       8    xx   17   1.0  
1       8    xy   19   1.0 
2       8    zz   13   0.0
3       9    tt   8    5.0
```

I am trying to create a dictionary that has a key  with a list of tuples 
like the following:

```
{8:[(17,1.0),(19,1.0),(13,0.0)], 9:[(8,5.0)]}
```

Here, the key comes from column a and the list of tuples are the column c and column d who have key as a. I am applying this on other datasets as well and have tried

```
df_new = df.groupby(['a'])[['c','d']).apply(lambda x: [tuple(x) for x in x.values])
```

However, I keep getting the error

```
raise TypeError('Series.name must be a hashable type')
TypeError: Series.name must be a hashable type
```

I have tried to remove ['a'] in the groupby and keep it as 'a' as follows:

```
df_new = df.groupby('a')[['c','d']).apply(lambda x: [tuple(x) for x in x.values])
```

But, I get the same following error:

```
raise TypeError('Series.name must be a hashable type')
TypeError: Series.name must be a hashable type
```

I don't want to make everything immutable in the original dataframe df. I want to keep it as is.

Is there a way to accomplish this using pandas functionality? I really don't want to make lists and then zip some together by their index and create a dict out of that.

Comment: What is your pandas version? `print (pd.show_versions())` ?

Answer (score 5):

***using `defaultdict`***

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for tup in df.itertuples():
    d[tup.a].append((tup.c, tup.d))

dict(d)

{8: [(17, 1.0), (19, 1.0), (13, 0.0)], 9: [(8, 5.0)]}
```

***using `to_dict` and `groupby` ***

```
df.set_index(['c', 'd']).groupby('a').apply(lambda df: df.index.tolist()).to_dict()

{8: [(17, 1.0), (19, 1.0), (13, 0.0)], 9: [(8, 5.0)]}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it is bug, but work `apply` with `zip`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'d': [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 5.0], 
                   'b': ['xx', 'xy', 'zz', 'tt'], 
                   'a': [8, 8, 8, 9], 
                   'c': [17, 19, 13, 8]})
print (df)
   a   b   c    d
0  8  xx  17  1.0
1  8  xy  19  1.0
2  8  zz  13  0.0
3  9  tt   8  5.0

df_new = df.groupby(['a']).apply(lambda x: list(zip(x.c, x.d))).to_dict()
print (df_new)
{8: [(17, 1.0), (19, 1.0), (13, 0.0)], 9: [(8, 5.0)]}
```

For me your version works to (there was small typo, `)` was changed to `]`):

```
df_new = df.groupby('a')[['c','d']].apply(lambda x: [tuple(x) for x in x.values]).to_dict()
print (df_new)
{8: [(17.0, 1.0), (19.0, 1.0), (13.0, 0.0)], 9: [(8.0, 5.0)]}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just another slight variation

```
df.set_index('a')[['c', 'd']]\
  .apply(tuple, 1)\
  .groupby(level=0)\
  .apply(list)\
  .to_dict()

{8: [(17, 1), (19, 1), (13, 0)], 9: [(8, 5)]}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
{k: list(map(tuple, g[['c','d']].values)) for k, g in df.groupby('a')}
# {8: [(17, 1), (19, 1), (13, 0)], 9: [(8, 5)]}
```

---

Or another way:

```
dict((k, list(map(tuple, g[['c','d']].values))) for k, g in df.groupby('a'))
```

Comment: This tells me "['a'] not in index"